# why does function return false from AtlasDB and true for my local version

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am checking to see whether or not a `user` of collection `users` exists within Atlas:MongoDB. **When I query my local version, I get true as expected. When I query AtlasDB I get false**. I want the query to return true for AtlasDB, because it's supposed to be the exact same data I copied over.

[image: Local DB user document]

[image: AtlasDB user document]

My Query: `let isUser = await userDB.isValidUser(username, password);`

```
let isValidUser = async function(username, password){
    return user.exists({'userID': username, 'password': password});
}
```

I know that my mongoose connection is good; no errors or timeouts or anything. *So why does the isValidUser() function not return `true` when mongoose is connected to the AtlasDB version?*

I have tried:

- *Refreshing Atlas DB* and making sure I have the newest connection string just in case that changed
- Verifying that the exact *same query/inputs work when accessing AtlasDB through the shell*
- Verifying that it's the same query inputs by debugging through the app for both cases: When querying localDB and when querying AtlasDB.

Comment: not sure it matters but just return rather than awaiting twice `return user.exists`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not specifying the DB name in my connection string. While the connection did reach the cluster, it was looking for a 'test' db that AtlasDB puts in by default.

Default connection AtlasDB provides:

```
mongodb+srv://<Username>:<Password>@cluster0-vbexh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I just needed to replace test with my DB name.